# Sending messages over Wifi to a Android / iPhone

Tags: wireless, android, iphone

Is it possible to send any kind of notification message in text to an Android or iPhone device from an Ubuntu terminal using WiFi only?

How the text is sent to the device is not important other than it must be seen by the user.

I will be using Ubuntu 14.04 Server 64bit to do this task.

The purpose of the task is to send out a notification every time the Ubuntu Server connects to the Wi-Fi network. The receiver of the notification should be all the Android / iPhone devices on the same network.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-)  Could you please give us a bit more information like: What version of Android/Ubuntu you're running?  What kind of message you're talking about? (DBusMessage, SMS Message, Using your machine's modem to call your phone's voice mail and leave a voice message, ...)  **;-)**

Comment: Hi Abby and thanks for your answer :) It is not important how the message is shown on the device. It just have to be seen by the user. I was not clear enough but it has to be text :) It has to be over wifi only.

Comment: For the future, please [edit] your question and specify that kind of necessary information, so we can better help you as in the [example](http://askubuntu.com/posts/604154/revisions) above.  ;-)
Please do the same to add the Ubuntu version you're running.

Comment: Hi Fabby. I am sorry for the lack of information. I am a nooby at askubuntu ;) I will edit my original question.

Comment: Voted to re-open question as it is much more clear now.